# How Promises are executed inside a Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, promise, scope

If I have a function with 3 Promises, they are supposed to run one after another, in the other they are appeared in the code of the function? I have a code where, in the third and last promise, I should have access to  variables `size` and `total`, assigned inside the other 2 promises, but they remain `undefined`. Am I missing something about this concept of Promisses? I just start learning about them very recently.

my code:

```
function update_cart() {
  var cart_size = document.getElementById('cart_size');
  var cart_status = document.getElementById('cart_status');
  var cart_total = document.getElementById('cart_total');

  var size, total;

  var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if(cart_size !== null) {
      var cliente = cart_size.dataset.cliente;
      var url = cart_size.dataset.url;

      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("POST", url, true);
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
          resolve(xhr.responseText);
        }
      };
      var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("cliente", cliente);
      xhr.send(formData);
    } else {
      reject();
    }
  });

  promise1.then(function(value) {
    size = value;
    cart_size.innerHTML = size;
    if(size == 0)
      cart_size.style.display = 'none';
    else
      cart_size.style.display = 'block';
  }).catch(function(){
    console.log('erro1');
  });

  var promise2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if(cart_total !== null) {
      var cliente = cart_total.dataset.cliente;
      var url = cart_total.dataset.url;

      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("POST", url, true);
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
          resolve(xhr.responseText);
        }
      };
      var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("cliente", cliente);
      xhr.send(formData);
    } else {
      reject();
    }
  });

  promise2.then(function(value) {
    total = value;
    var currency = new Intl.NumberFormat('pt-BR', { style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL' }).format(total);
    cart_total.innerHTML = currency;
  }).catch(function(){
    console.log('erro2');
  });

  var promise3 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if(cart_status !== null) {
      resolve();
    } else {
      reject();
    }
  });

  promise3.then(function() {
    console.log('promise3');
    console.log('size: '+size+', total: '+total);
    switch(size) {
      case 0:
        cart_status.innerHTML = 'A cesta de compras está vazia.';
        document.getElementById('table').style.display = 'none';
        break;
      case 1:
        cart_status.innerHTML = size + ' produto adicionado na cesta, com valor ' + total;
        document.getElementById('table').style.display = 'block';
        break;
      default:
        cart_status.innerHTML = size + ' produtos adicionados na cesta, com valor ' + total;
        document.getElementById('table').style.display = 'block';
        break;
    }
  }).catch(function(){
    console.log('erro3');
  });
}
```

Comment: Your second and third promises are created outside of each other.  They are all on the same level.  And I don't see any sort of `await` logical attempts.  Why are you expecting them to run sequentially?

Comment: Like I said, maybe I misundertood something about how Promises work. How this await logical would work here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promise execution does not block the calling function. Hence your all 3 promises are executed immediately resulting in the `undefined` value in `size` and `total` variables. Try this :

```
function update_cart() {
  var cart_size = document.getElementById("cart_size");
  var cart_status = document.getElementById("cart_status");
  var cart_total = document.getElementById("cart_total");

  var size, total;

  var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (cart_size !== null) {
      var cliente = cart_size.dataset.cliente;
      var url = cart_size.dataset.url;

      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("POST", url, true);
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
          resolve(xhr.responseText);
        }
      };
      var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("cliente", cliente);
      xhr.send(formData);
    } else {
      reject();
    }
  });

  var promise2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (cart_total !== null) {
      var cliente = cart_total.dataset.cliente;
      var url = cart_total.dataset.url;

      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("POST", url, true);
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
          resolve(xhr.responseText);
        }
      };
      var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("cliente", cliente);
      xhr.send(formData);
    } else {
      reject();
    }
  });

  var promise3 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (cart_status !== null) {
      resolve();
    } else {
      reject();
    }
  });

  promise1
    .then(function(value) {
      size = value;
      cart_size.innerHTML = size;
      if (size == 0) cart_size.style.display = "none";
      else cart_size.style.display = "block";

      promise2
        .then(function(value) {
          total = value;
          var currency = new Intl.NumberFormat("pt-BR", {
            style: "currency",
            currency: "BRL"
          }).format(total);
          cart_total.innerHTML = currency;

          promise3
            .then(function() {
              console.log("promise3");
              console.log("size: " + size + ", total: " + total);
              switch (size) {
                case 0:
                  cart_status.innerHTML = "A cesta de compras está vazia.";
                  document.getElementById("table").style.display = "none";
                  break;
                case 1:
                  cart_status.innerHTML =
                    size + " produto adicionado na cesta, com valor " + total;
                  document.getElementById("table").style.display = "block";
                  break;
                default:
                  cart_status.innerHTML =
                    size + " produtos adicionados na cesta, com valor " + total;
                  document.getElementById("table").style.display = "block";
                  break;
              }
            })
            .catch(function() {
              console.log("erro3");
            });
        })
        .catch(function() {
          console.log("erro2");
        });
    })
    .catch(function() {
      console.log("erro1");
    });
}
```

I just moved the next promise's invocations the the previous promise's callback, so that each one gets executed only after the previous one is complete. If you require some other order, or need to parallelize requests read more about promises [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).

Comment: That won't work if the user needs separate error handler for each promise. You can also do `async` `await`, which is much neater. The purpose of this answer was to explain the working of a promise, as close to his source code. Now how it should be written can be left to the deveoper.

Comment: Well, your answer is a bad design pattern to teach, regardless of what else it shows.  It doesn't chain the promises (which can still be done with a separate catch handler for each one - though a separate catch handler is not actually needed here) and it doesn't communicate back completion or error to caller.  This is never how one should sequence promise-based actions.

Comment: Agreed. I could have completely refactored this into async await which for me is the cleanest way of writing multiple promises at the moment in Javascript scene. Didn't want to sidetrack from the question we have in hand.

Comment: IMO, any answer you post should teach a good design pattern.  That's my point here.  You had them reorganize their code, but it's still not a good way to teach someone.  If you have to refactor a bit more in order to show a good way of solving the problem, that's what I would suggest.  One does not have to use async/await here to have a good design pattern, but that certainly is one of the viable choices (if browser support allows).

Answer (score 1):

The three promises are being executed at the same time since you are initializing them before waiting for any to finish. If you want the promises to run one after the other and be able to catch different errors for different promises you should use async/await:

```js
async function update_cart() {
  // ...
  try {
    var value = await promise1;
    size = value;
    // Rest of code inside promise1.then
  } catch(err) {
    console.log('erro1');
  }
}
```

Repeat that for promise2 and promise3. The function update_cart will now return a Promise that resolves when promise1, promise2 and promise3 all resolve, one after the other